# How to share a directory using C++ so everyone can access

Tags: c++, directory

I'm trying to make a program so that when it run, it will create a new folder on C://. I also want to add a feature where the folder can have a shared permission to everyone. So, everyone can access and read/write

I've tried using netshareadd but I always got a compiler warning, how do I get rid of it?

This is creating new directory code :

```
#include <direct.h>
    int main()
    {
          mkdir("c:/scan");
          return 0;
    }
```

This is the netshareadd code :

```
    #ifndef UNICODE
    #define UNICODE
    #endif
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <lm.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "Netapi32.lib")

    void wmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[ ])
    {
       NET_API_STATUS res;
       SHARE_INFO_2 p;
       DWORD parm_err = 0;

       if(argc<2)
          printf("Usage: NetShareAdd server\n");
       else
       {
          //
          // Fill in the SHARE_INFO_2 structure.
          //
          p.shi2_netname = TEXT("TESTSHARE");    
          p.shi2_type = STYPE_DISKTREE; // disk drive
          p.shi2_remark = TEXT("TESTSHARE to test NetShareAdd");
          p.shi2_permissions = 0;    
          p.shi2_max_uses = 4;
          p.shi2_current_uses = 0;    
          p.shi2_path = TEXT("C:\\scan");
          p.shi2_passwd = NULL; // no password
          //
          // Call the NetShareAdd function,
          //  specifying level 2.
          //
          res=NetShareAdd(argv[1], 2, (LPBYTE) &p, &parm_err);
          //
          // If the call succeeds, inform the user.
          //
          if(res==0)
             printf("Share created.\n");

          // Otherwise, print an error,
          //  and identify the parameter in error.
          //
          else
             printf("Error: %u\tparmerr=%u\n", res, parm_err);
       }
       return;
    }
```

> 22    22  D:\kerja\NETSHARE.cpp   [Warning] deprecated conversion from
>   string constant to 'LPWSTR {aka wchar_t*}' [-Wwrite-strings]

This is the warning that I always got when compiling the netshareadd code

Comment: The *'error'* pretty much rather sounds like a compiler warning – do you really get it when *running* the programme or already when *compiling*?

Comment: @Aconcagua i got it when compiling

Comment: I know... My bad, question wasn't obviously enough rhetorical. But you might fix your question.

Answer (score 2):

[NetShareAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netshareadd) requires a non const parameter. Some Windows APIs modify the passed buffer (or are way old) so you need a wchar_t*, not a const wchar_t* which is what a L"string" produces.

Solution, copy the const wchar_t* into a vector and pass the vector's data() member to the function (don't forget the null terminator).

Comment: hello do you have example for this? I dont think I quite grasp how to do it

Comment: `std::vector`? Simpler: `wchar_t buffer[] = L"some string";`

Comment: @DwiNovitasari Somewhere before the call to `NetShareAdd` – and use it as parameter for the call.

Comment: Why a `std::vector`?  What's wrong with plain old `std::wstring`?

Comment: @TobySpeight std::string will return a *const* wchar_t*

Comment: It did in older versions of C++ (pre C++17).  But modern code gets a modifiable `data()` from a modifiable string.